# I don't have access to get all invitable_friends at Facebook API using javascript

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get all facebook invitable friends, yesterday it was working, but today the facebook API has return that

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) No permission to access invitable_friends.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "ApJrz2NAGPx"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your app a game?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to being a game, you must have the Canvas platform set up. And you must have a *playable* version of your game *on canvas*. If that is not the case, then you are not allowed to use invitable_friends in the first place.

Possible alternatives for inviting friends are explained here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_1291953124230220

Comment: i am not using it in a game just using it in website to fetch friends list but getting same error any solution please

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla: Again, in other situations than for game apps with a canvas implementation, you can not use invite requests. You are simply not allowed to, and Facebook will deny it in review. And, also again, alternatives for other types of apps are listed in the FAQ.